# 50 shades of grey

Tags: c#, colors, hex

I would like to get different shades of grey based on a number `intervals` and a position (`index`) in that interval count.

So the function would be something like:

```
public static string GetShade(string StartColour, string EndColour, int Intervals, int Index)
{ ... }
```

So it would return:

```
 GetShade("#aaaaaa", "#eeeeee", 5, 2) = "#bbbbbb"
 GetShade("#333333", "#555555", 3, 3) = "#555555"
```

(Obviously it would only be pertinent to grey, if my start & end were grey).

Any pointers?

Comment: Try it yourself: Chop up the color into its R, G and B components, calculate the difference, divide it by the interval and add the result `index` times to the start value.

Comment: are all your grey shades in the form #ababab or can they be in any form? HSL would be a much better model for getting greys.

Comment: @marabutt good point; but let's point out that this is not needed for "pure" gray-scale images, where R, G, and B are equal. It is however needed for sepia or other tones...

Comment: Titles.. Sometimes they are only good part of the questions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you need some special string representation should be put outside of your function. Handling colors is a task. Formatting colors to and from a string is another task and should be handled by another function.

The basic math spelled out in detail goes like this:

```
      public static Color GetShade(Color start, Color end, byte intervals, byte index)
      {
        var deltaR = end.R - start.R;
        var deltaG = end.G - start.G;
        var deltaB = end.B - start.B;

        var intervalR = deltaR / intervals;
        var intervalG = deltaG / intervals;
        var intervalB = deltaB / intervals;

        var finalR = start.R + (index * intervalR);
        var finalG = start.G + (index * intervalG);
        var finalB = start.B + (index * intervalB);

        return new Color { R = (byte)finalR, G = (byte)finalG, B = (byte)finalB };
      }
```

Comment: As its grey R,B and B will be the same value

Comment: Thanks - this is what I needed. I store the colours as strings in the DB, but I'll convert to colours before using this function, so it's more reusable. I'm not sure why intervals & index are bytes though? I'll play around with that.

Comment: It's because the R/G/B values are bytes, so for perfect greys (R=G=B) there's only 255 possible shades. Having more than 255 intervals doesn't make a lot of sense for that and having more indices than intervals would make sense either :)

Answer (score 2):

Each of the components of the colour is a hex representation of a number between 0 and 255.

All you will need to do is to do:

```
int shade = 255/Intervals * index;
return string.format("{0:X}{0:X}{0:X}", shade);
```

There may be some rounding-type issues with the above but above is the general concept needed.

Comment: Sorry, seeing other comments it should be:return string.format("{0:X2}{0:X2}{0:X2}", shade);

Answer (score 2):

Well, you didn't mention a lot regarding what you tried so far, so I guess you're stuck at the very beginning.

I'd probably approach this as follows:

1. Dissect the start and end colours into their three components as numbers from the strings (you can't really calculate with strings)
2. Figure out the required answer by dividing the interval (*start*, *end*) and picking the correct split (simple arithmetic, should be something like *start* + (*end* − *start*) ÷ *intervals* · *index*)
3. Re-assemble the colour string. Take care to allow for leading zeroes, i.e. use something like `string.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", r, g, b)`.